# All logins are being accepted by the program, unsure as to why

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I've been experimenting with a sqlite3 for the first time and was developing a login system (with some help from articles and videos) and have noticed that all credentials inputted into the program are being accepted, I can't find a fault in the program so I could use some help.

## Importing Important Libraries

```
import sqlite3
import bcrypt


    class Database:
     
        def __init__(self):
            try:
                self.conn = sqlite3.connect("usertable.db")
                print("Successfully Opened Database")
                self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
            except:
                print("Failed")
    
        def createTable(self):
    
            create_table = '''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cred(
                    id Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    username TEXT NOT NULL,
                    password TEXT NOT NULL
                );
            '''
    
            self.curr.execute(create_table)
            self.conn.commit()
    
        def insertData(self, data):
    
            insert_data = """
                INSERT INTO cred(username, password)
                VALUES(?, ?);
            """
            
            self.curr.execute(insert_data, data)
            self.conn.commit()
    
        def searchData(self, data):
    
            search_data = '''
                SELECT * FROM cred WHERE username = (?);
            '''
    
            self.curr.execute(search_data, data)
    
            rows = self.curr.fetchall()
    
            if rows == []:
                return 1
            return 0
    
        def validateData(self, data, inputData):
            validate_data = """
                SELECT * FROM cred WHERE username = (?);
            """
    
            self.curr.execute(validate_data, data)
            row = self.curr.fetchall()
    
            if row[0][1] == inputData[0]:
                return row[0][2] == bcrypt.hashpw(inputData[1].encode(), row[0][2])
    
    
    
    
    (The login and register classes)
    
    
    
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import bcrypt
    from database import Database
    
    
    db = Database()
    db.createTable()
    
    class Login:
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.loginWindow = Tk()
            self.loginWindow.title("Login")
            self.loginWindow.geometry("300x250")
            self.label = Label(self.loginWindow, text="Login")
            self.label.place(x=95, y=40)
    
            self.usernames = StringVar()
            self.passwords = StringVar()
    
            self.usernameE = Entry(self.loginWindow, relief=FLAT, textvariable=self.usernames)
            self.usernameE.place(x=70, y=80)
            self.passwordE = Entry(self.loginWindow, show="*", relief=FLAT, textvariable = self.passwords)
            self.passwordE.place(x=70, y=120)
            
            self.username = self.usernames.get()
            self.password = self.passwords.get()
    
            self.submit = Button(self.loginWindow, text = "Submit", pady = 5, padx = 20, command = self.validate)
            self.submit.place(x=100, y=150)
        
        def validate(self):
            data = (self.username,)
            inputData = (self.username, self.password,)
            try:
                if (db.validateData(data, inputData)):
                    messagebox.showinfo("Successful", "Login Was Successful")
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Credentials")
            except IndexError:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Credentials")
    
        def run(self):
            self.loginWindow.mainloop()
    
    
    
    class Register:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.registerWindow = Tk()
            self.registerWindow.title("Register")
            self.registerWindow.geometry("300x250")
            self.label = Label(self.registerWindow, text="Register")
    
            self.usernameS = StringVar()
            self.passwordS = StringVar()
    
            self.usernameE = Entry(self.registerWindow, relief = FLAT, textvariable = self.usernameS)
            self.usernameE.place(x=70, y=80)
            self.passwordE = Entry(self.registerWindow, show="*", relief = FLAT, textvariable = self.passwordS)
            self.passwordE.place(x=70, y=120)
            self.submit = Button(self.registerWindow, text="Submit", pady = 5, padx = 20, command = self.add)
            self.submit.place(x=100, y=150)
    
            self.username = self.usernameS.get()
            self.password = self.passwordS.get()
    
            self.salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
            self.hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(self.password.encode(), self.salt)
    
        def run(self):
            self.registerWindow.mainloop()
    
        def add(self):
            data = (self.username,)
    
            result = db.searchData(data)
    
            print(result, result, result)
            
            if result != 0:
                data = (self.username, self.hashed)
                db.insertData(data)
                messagebox.showinfo("Successful", "Username Was Added")
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Username already Exists")
    
    
    
    
    (The main window class)
    
    
    
    
    from tkinter import *
    from login import Login, Register
    
    
    class Window(object):
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.window = Tk()
            self.window.title("Login Screen")
            self.window.geometry("300x250")
            self.label = Label(self.window, text = "Welcome to Login")
            self.label.place(x=95, y=40)
            self.login = Button(self.window, text = "Login", pady = 5, padx = 30, command = login)
            self.login.place(x=100, y=100)
            self.register = Button(self.window, text = "Register", pady = 5, padx = 20, command = register)
            self.register.place(x=100, y=150)
    
    
    
        def run(self):
            self.window.mainloop()
    
    
    def login():
        loginTk = Login()
        loginTk.run()
    
    def register():
        registerTk = Register()
        registerTk.run()
    
    
    window = Window()
    window.run()
```

The program is stored in 3 different files (the login and register classes are stored within the same file.)

Comment: Generally speaking, you should avoid writing your own security modules entirely, find an existing (well-test) library to do it for you.

Comment: You should call `self.username = self.usernames.get()` and `self.password = self.passwords.get()` inside `Login.validate()` function.  Also recommend to hash the user input password first, then use the hashed password in the WHERE clause of the SQL statement.